# Xcode calculations with multi-component picker

Tags: xcode, picker

I would like to set up a view controller with a 2-component picker where each side contains the same 7 objects. Each object carries the same value for both components. The user would make a selection from each side, enter a value in a provided text field (and optionally tap a "Calculate" button). A calculation would occur using that value and the values from the two picker component objects that were selected and the results would be displayed in a label.

For example, each picker contains the letters a - g. Each letter carries the value of 1 - 7 respectively, for each side of the picker. The user selects "b" and "d" and enters 10. The calculated result of 10 * 2 / 4 = 5 is displayed.

It sounds simple enough. I've found tutorials for doing calculations using values associated with a 1-component picker as well as working with 2-component pickers, but nothing for doing calculations with 2-component pickers. My experience with Xcode is somewhat short. So, feel free to go into detail.

Comment: What particular part are you having trouble with? Do you have anything you've tried already that is half-working or not working? It's hard to know where to start answering this.

Comment: I posed the same concern [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11546164/how-to-code-calculations-in-xcode-using-2-component-picker-and-text-field-entry) in much more detail (including code snippets), but got no response. So I thought I'd try a more basic approach. Basically, I need to know how to make sure the desired numerical values are associated with the correct picker objects, how to consolidate this if possible since both picker components use the same objects and values, and how to incorporate the values from each picker object selection into a single calculation.